# Independent Columns in the same table after join

Tags: mysql, sql

Given 2 tables like:

```
table name: users

user_gender  user_registration_timestamp
Male         2019-11-07 00:00:00
Male         2019-11-08 00:00:00
Female       2019-11-09 00:00:00
Other        2019-11-10 00:00:00
Female       2020-11-11 00:00:00
```

and

```
table name: informations

info_clicks  info_timestamp
15           2019-11-07 00:00:00
1            2019-11-08 00:00:00
22           2019-11-09 00:00:00
7            2019-11-11 00:00:00
1            2020-11-11 00:00:00
```

I need to build a query that returns:

```
a)Per day in 2019 the number of clicks and (independently) the number of registrations
```

And a second query that returns:

```
b)Per day with info_clicks in 2019 the number of clicks and the number of registrations
```

I tried an inner join with a 'calendar' table contaning all dates between 2018 and 2020, but I'm not getting the expected result

Comment: please provide your desired output in table format

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two result sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These queries should do it:

```
/* Show every date in 2019 */
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n, dt) AS (
    SELECT 1, '2019-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, n, '2019-01-01') FROM cte WHERE n < 365
)
SELECT dt, ucount, ccount FROM cte
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(users.user_registration_timestamp) AS regdate, count(*) AS ucount
     FROM users 
     GROUP BY regdate) u on cte.dt = u.regdate
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(info_timestamp) AS clickdate, SUM(info_clicks) AS ccount 
     FROM informations
     GROUP BY clickdate) i on cte.dt = i.clickdate     
ORDER BY 1

/* Show only dates with clicks in 2019 */
WITH clicks2019 AS (SELECT date(info_timestamp) AS clickdate, sum(info_clicks) AS ccount 
     FROM informations WHERE year(info_timestamp) = 2019
     GROUP BY clickdate)
SELECT * FROM clicks2019
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(users.user_registration_timestamp) AS regdate, COUNT(*) AS ucount
     FROM users 
     GROUP BY regdate) u ON clicks2019.clickdate = u.regdate
ORDER BY 1
```

Demo is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e5acaa001773b0a46a432ea1f0a4fde6)